# How to remove a row from a ListView when I am using a custom Adapter with two buttons

Tags: android

I am using using a ListView which has two Buttons and a EditText in it, `button1` will change the edit text to "Clicked!" and `button2` will delete the row whose button been clicked.

I am not finding any way how to do it from `ActivityMain`.

Comment: Can you please include a [mcve] for the code and layouts you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a Adapter for your ListView. For first you should use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) instead of ListView. Make your own custom Adapter and use for example ArrayList to keep your items. Then if you would like to delete something you will have to remove it from ArrayList and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Here is the toutorial how to do it: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom list view with a custom adapter, you can handle onclick listeners of buttons from within the adapter itself by first getting the view and then like

```
Button btn1 = (Button) yourview.findviewbyid(R.id.btnxx);
```

**Note yourview.findviewbyid**

Comment: How does this help "remove the row"?

Comment: Question is tagged android only, no database and/or connection is mentioned and from the question, it is easy to assume what questioner is trying to achieve.

Comment: I didn't say (or assume) anything about databases.... You can remove items from a ListView without a database, but this answer doesn't mention anything about how to do what, which seems to be what the question is asking. Not only how to get a reference to a button